# Custom character classes in Emacs' regexp

Tags: regex, emacs, elisp

Is it possible to add own character classes to emacs in order to use them in regular expressions?

Let's say, i want to add a class `[[:consonant:]]` which matches all letters that are not vowels in order to avoid writing `[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]` all the time (and yes, i am aware that my shortcut is almost as long as the term i want to avoid, take it as a simplification of my problem).

Is this possible at all or do i have to use `format` or `concat`, respectively? If it is possible, how do i do that?

An MWE could be like this:

```
(defun myfun ()
  "Finds clusters of three or more consonants"
  (interactive)
  (if (search-forward-regexp "[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]\\{3,\\}")
    (message "Yepp, here is a consonant cluster.")
))

(defun myfun-1 ()
  "Should also find clusters of three or more consonants."
  (interactive)
  (if (search-forward-regexp "[[:consonant:]]\\{3,\\}")
    (message "Yepp, here is a consonant cluster.")
))
```

Both functions `myfun` and `myfun-1` should do the very same thing.

One step further i'd like to know if it is possible to put whole expressions in such "shortcuts", like

```
[[:ending:]] ==> "\\(?:en\\|st\\|t\\|e\\)"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jordon-Biondo is correct, you cannot extend Emacs' character classes for regexp search.  If you peek into Emacs' source code, you can see these defined in the routine `re_wctype_parse` on line 1510(ish) of [regex-emacs.c](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/src/regex-emacs.c).  So adding to these natively would require modifying the .c file and rebuilding.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe you can do this. But there is something similar that was recently released in the [ample-regexp package found HERE.](https://github.com/immerrr/ample-regexps.el) This was taken from the readme as an example:

```
(define-arx h-w-rx
  '((h "Hello, ")
    (w "world"))) ;; -> hello-world-rx

(h-w-rx h w) ;; -> "Hello, world"

(h-w-rx (* h w)) ;; -> "\\(?:Hello, world\\)*"
```

You could use this to define a wide range of aliases in one big define-arx.